# How to generate Angular components based on a set of markdown files?

Tags: angular, markdown

I am looking for a solution to generate Angular components using markdown files (that would be put for example in: `assets/posts` and `assets/pages`).

I am trying to generate a static website using Angular, but without Jekyll stuff.

The deployment just targets a Github Pages repository.

I found this solution below that leverages Jekyll .*md but I am looking at how to build something from scratch since the projet is not really updated: 
https://github.com/kevinphelps/ng-static-site-generator-starter/tree/master/src

Comment: It's not clear about the environment you're going to generate the code. Is it a fully controlled server or at least your local machine?

Comment: @Envil fixed: it aims at puting the Angular dist content on a Github Pages repository.

Comment: Github Pages doesn't let you run any custom build command, unless you precompile your code then push to the repo.

Comment: This https://github.com/kevinphelps/ng-static-site-generator-starter/tree/master/src is firebase, not Github Pages

Comment: @Envil that's clearly my intent that's why I mentioned the content of dist folder which content everything the blog needs.
I know it leverages "firebase", just the closest thing I found related to what I would like to achieve...

Comment: Sorry but I have no idea what you're imagining about. Good luck!